# Parse JSON Array

Tags: java, json

My JSON is something like this:

```
[{
        "myviews":[{
                "2011-05-12_2011-05-14":{
                    "name":"thiswk",
                    "data":[[12,
                            2403
                        ],
                        [13,
                            2082
                        ],
                        [14,
                            5823
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "2011-06-05_2011-06-7":{
                    "name":"lastwk",
                    "data":[[5,
                            1279
                        ],
                        [6,
                            6685
                        ],
                        [7,
                            2163
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

```
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray ja;
    jo = jo.getJSONObject("2011-05-12_2011-05-14");
    ja = jo.getJSONArray("data");
    int resultCount = ja.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
    {
        JSONObject resultObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
        resultObject.getJSONArray("12");
        System.out.println("--");
    }
```

I am unable to read the values under the "data" array. Get this error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject
>   text must begin with '{' at character
>   1

Comment: Did you try removing the `[` at the beginning and the `]` in the end? Like the error says, `JSONObject` requires the first character to be `{`!

Comment: Why do you not believe the error message?

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to create a JSONObject based on a string that doesn't represent an object, but an array containing one object.

To get the contained object, try

```
JSONArray inputArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
JSONObject jo = inputArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

I think some of your later work is wrong as well, but perhaps this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

`data` appears to be an array of arrays.  Perhaps you need to call `ja.getJSONArray(i)`?