# How to retrieve values from a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

this is the JSONArray: 
String json = [{"1":"Kenny", "2":"Tom", "3":"Mosoti"}];
now i want to get a string array of values only eg Kenny, Tom, Mosoti

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You may use any json parser to do that for instance [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

It is not a good option to write your own parser as it is error-prone. Also don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: am using this package org.json.*

Comment: help me out using the package

Comment: @user1759570 have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402115/parse-json-array)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should go with a mainstream library/framework like Jackson, you can read more about it here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

A basic example would be something like:

```
private static MailData unMarshallJson(String literalJson) throws JAXBException, IOException {
    Data data = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    data = mapper.readValue(literalJson, Data.class);

    return data;
}
```

Where the Data class is a class corresponding to the parsed data, read the link that I provided for more info.