# How to Parse JSON Array in Android

Tags: android, json

I am getting resposne from web service :-

```
response = [{"result":"false"}]
```

I am not getting How to Parse this

Thanks Advance.

Comment: see here- http://stackoverflow.com/a/14562462/1225413

Comment: here too- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6402216/1225413

Comment: i had tried this but not working i need urgent ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObjet obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
String result = obj.getString("result");
```

this should do the trick.

if you're trying to parse more than on object you can use a `for-loop` and if you're not sure if you have a field, you can use this line:

```
if(obj.has("result"){
    String result = obj.getString("result");
}
```